# Como tirar foto via serviços no android?

Tags: android, android-camera

Preciso desenvolver uma app para tirar fotos sem que o usuário perceba, como nos programas antifurto que existem hoje.

Preciso que o celular abra o app da câmera e tire uma foto quando o celular ou telefone receber um alerta de que foi roubado.

Como posso me aprofundar nessa pesquisa e conseguir uma solução?

Comment: Talvez isso ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467806/simple-way-to-hide-capturing-camera-on-android

Comment: Você pode tentar por uma preview com tamanho mínimo gerada pelo serviço. Observe essa resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10268650

Comment: hmm não era exatamente como eu queria... estou tentando buscar algum exemplo para ver como faz mas não acho nada.

Comment: seu app será um app antifurto ou você usou isso apenas para comparação? o "(...)sem que o usuário perceba, como nos programas antifurto(...)" deixou implícito que você apenas usou como exemplo e quer usar em um projeto diferente

Comment: Quero fazer um exemplo de antifurto para um trabalho. Tenho a api pronta e toda arquitetura OK. Porém não estou conseguindo desenvolver essa funcionalidade. Queria um exemplo de como conseguir tirar fotos sem o Preview.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro o celular tem de descobrir que foi roubado. Acredito que a ideia seja que, de um site, a pessoa diga que o celular foi roubado e uma informação seja enviada ao mesmo.

Para comunicação App x Servidor (se for esse o caso), acredito que deva se informar sobre webservice. 
O App pode perguntar de vez em quando ao servidor se ele *é roubado ou não*, e receber uma resposta. 
Deixar o app "oculto" não tem como. O "dono" do celular poderá ver nas tarefas que este app existe e está rodando.

Pode-se chamar algum software que tire fotos de dentro da "app de segurança", tirar uma foto e pega-la da galeria.
Ou pode-se tirar a foto direto do seu app.

Uma das respostas aqui deve resolver parte da tua dúvida:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729267/android-camera-intent

Aqui é como pegar a imagem que está na galeria, se for o caso.
http://blog.vogella.com/2011/09/13/android-how-to-get-an-image-via-an-intent/

Mais informações uteis.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-picture

Comment: Sim... mas possuo toda a estrutura e tenho a api pronta para o App Antifurto única função que estou penando mesmo é a da câmera. Consegui algumas vezes mas a qualidade da câmera frontal ficou tenebrosa e em alguns dispositivos o app dá erro. O que eu quero é tirar foto sem a preview da câmera.

Comment: @ArilsonCarmo, você pode simplesmente reduzir a área de `preview` para o mínimo possível (1px x 1px) e 'escondê-la' em algum canto da interface.

Comment: Tem algum exemplo?